# Use useQuery() (react-query) as a custom hook right or wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I use useQuery() to receive data from the server.
In order not to repeat the API site address and a series of additional parameters each time, I used the following custom hook:

```
export function useGetApi(mode, params, key) {

  // get initial config from context:
  const { config } = useGetConfig();

  const url = `https://example.com/api/${ mode }/?${ params }&lang_code=${ config.language }`;
  const queryKey = `${key}_${config.language}`;


  // async function for get API:
  async function getApi() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    return data;
  }

  return useQuery(['getApi', queryKey], getApi, {
    enabled: !!config.language
  });
}
```

A series of basic settings, including language, are located in a context called "Config".
In every component and every need I have, I call this custom hook and fill in the arguments, for example:

```
const { isLoading, data: products } = useGetApi(`products`, `company_id=${companyId}`, `products_${companyId}`);
```

Is this wrong?

Comment: Look what axios instance is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think that there's no problem in what you did. The beauty of React is that you are free to build components and automation files to increase your productivity which is what you did.